# Calling JavaScript function before the end of body

Tags: javascript, html

How do I call a JavaScript function before the end of the body of an HTML page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script...>
    function helloWorld() {
        alert('Hello world!');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
...some content...
    <script...>
        helloWorld();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just place a `<script>` block in there, like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    myFunction();
  </script>
</body>
```

Also, if you're using a framework of some sort, most of them have handlers for when the DOM is ready, or you can use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload), whatever best fits your situation.